# Mapping many-to-many relationship with attributes with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Consider the following entity-relationship diagram

```
[PERSON] (*..N) ------ < is engaged into > ------ (*..N) [ACTIVITY]
                          /          \
                       hobby        duty
```

where `[PERSON]` and `[ACTIVITY]` are entities and `<is engaged into>` is a many-to-many relationship with attributes (flags) `hobby` and `duty`. The attributes are non-exclusive: both can be true or false independent of each other.

**How would one map this ERD to the Java object model shown below using JPA (or Hibernate)?**

```
@Entity
class Person {
    Collection<Activity> hobbies;     // only activities where hobby=true
    Collection<Activity> duties;      // only activities where duty=true
}


@Entity
class Activity{
    Collection<Person> aficionados;   // only people where hobby=true
    Collection<Person> professionals; // only people where duty=true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting case.

I made it work for me on JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 5.1.

Assuming that:

- Id of Person entity = PERSON_ID
- Id of Activity entity = ACTIVITY_ID
- Name of linking table = PERSON_ACTIVITY

**Person entity:**

```
@Entity
class Person {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_ACTIVITY",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "hobby = 1")
    Set<Activity>  hobbyActivities;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_ACTIVITY",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "duty = 1")
    Set<Activity>  dutyActivities;

}
```

**Activity entity:**

```
@Entity
class Activity{

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_ACTIVITY",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "hobby = 1")
    Set<Person>  hobbyPeople;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_ACTIVITY",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "duty = 1")
    Set<Person>  dutyPeople;
}
```

**Key points**:

- The collection has to be explicitly a Set in all of the cases
- One of the @ManyToMany sets in each entity has to be marked as lazy loaded
- While doing some testing i found that i had to use DISTINCT a lot of times not to get repeating results (but that was only maybe my case).

Comment: Map<Integer, Person> assigns a single person to an Integer key, but what I would like to have is a collection of people assigned to the key. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ill do some more tests later on.. after going again through your question i think we will need to go a different strategy

Comment: I have posted new solution. Check it out

Comment: Any luck with testing?

Comment: The solution worked very well, thank you. I also have realized that using a Set is much more appropriate than using the more general Collection in my case because the FKs in my join table make up the PK of that table and thus I do not have any duplicates.

Comment: Great. If you think my answer brought value to you i would appreciate you accepting it. Thanks